# How would I make this bubble sort more pythonic?

Tags: python, bubble-sort, python-3.9

I have this code:

```
Sorted=False
while not Sorted:
    Sorted=True
    for x,y in enumerate(List[:-1]):
        if List[x]>List[x+1]:
            List[x],List[x+1]=List[x+1],List[x]
            Sorted=False
```

However the use of

```
Sorted=True/False
```

being repeated is quite ugly and it would be much nicer to write the code is something similar to:

```
while True:
    for x,y in enumerate(List[:-1]):
        if List[x]>List[x+1]:
            List[x],List[x+1]=List[x+1],List[x]
            break
    else:break
```

The only problem is that breaking from the loop this early causes the loop to be repeated many more times taking up more time overall. Are there any ways around this to make the code more pythonic or do I just need to leave it as ugly as it is?

Comment: It might be better to ask on [codereview.se]

Comment: Using a boolean flag doesn't make your code unpythonic, sometimes its the best way to express your intention. For this code, the things that jump out at me are capitalized variable names, no spaces around operators, using "List" as a variable :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's really a better way to *structure* this Pythonically. I could raise some formatting quibbles, based on [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) recommendations, that would make your code easier to read:

- `snake_case` for variables (no capital letters)
- spaces around the `=` in assignment, after commas, and usually around comparisons

Additionally, I agree with [Stepan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67221895/12975140) that the for loop could simply use `range(len(...))`. Taking those into consideration (and then avoiding the reserved keywords that result, `sorted` and `list`):

```py
done_sorting = False
while not done_sorting:
    done_sorting = True
    for i in range(len(lst - 1)):
        if lst[i] > lst[i+1]:
            lst[i], lst[i+1] = lst[i+1], lst[i]
            done_sorting = False
```

Now, it's generally conventional wisdom that [`range(len(...))` is an antipattern](https://treyhunner.com/2016/04/how-to-loop-with-indexes-in-python/) in Python. As Trey Hunner concludes in that article:

> If you find yourself tempted to use `range(len(my_list))` or a loop counter, think about whether you can reframe your problem to allow usage of `zip` or `enumerate` (or a combination of the two).
>
> In fact, if you find yourself reaching for `enumerate`, think about whether you actually need indexes at all. It’s quite rare to need indexes in Python.

However, much of the reason for this is Python's array (pun intended) of builtin tools for iterating and sorting. If you wanted to sort a list purely as a practical matter, you'd be using `sorted()` or `.sort()`, not implementing your own bubble sort as an exercise. In this case, intentionally working with lower-level details as you are, it makes sense to work directly with the indices.

Just for kicks... If you really wanted to do this in the more "normally Pythonic" way, it might look something like this:

```py
done_sorting = False
while not done_sorting:
    done_sorting = True
    for (i, first), (j, second) in zip(enumerate(lst[:-1]), enumerate(lst[1:])):
        if first > second:
            lst[i], lst[j] = second, first
            done_sorting = False
```

And I don't think *anyone* would argue that improves readability.

---

P.S. It's not useful for bubble-sorting, since it doesn't give access to indices, but something related you might like to know about is the `pairwise` function. It's very convenient for looping over consecutive overlapping pairs in a list:

```py
for first, second in pairwise(lst):
```

It will be included in Python 3.10 as [`itertools.pairwise`](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/itertools.html#itertools.pairwise), but you can use it in earlier versions too:

- It's included in the installable [`more-itertools`](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#more_itertools.pairwise) package.
- The docs include a readymade [recipe](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes) for implementing it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

1. Your second version is not a bubble sort.
2. I would just change the loop to

   ```
     for idx in range(len(List)-1):
        if List[idx]>List[idx+1]:
            List[idx],List[idx+1] = List[idx+1],List[idx]
            Sorted=False
   ```